# heapq.nlargest index of returned result in original sequence

Tags: python, sorting, heap

How do I return the index in the original list of the nth largest items of an iterable

```
heapq.nlargest(2, [100, 2, 400, 500, 400])

output = [(3,500), (2, 400)]
```

This already cost me a couple hours. I can't figure it out.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

```
>>> seq = [100, 2, 400, 500, 400]
>>> heapq.nlargest(2, enumerate(seq), key=lambda x: x[1])
[(3, 500), (2, 400)]
```

Answer (score 6):

You can use [`list.index`](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html) in combination with [`map`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#map), which is fast for small `n` (beware the `list.index` returns the index in the list of the **first** item whose value is x):

```
>>> iterable = [100, 2, 400, 500, 400]
>>> map(iterable.index, heapq.nlargest(2, iterable))
[3, 2]
```

To see the associated values ...

```
>>> map(lambda n: (n, iterable.index(n)), heapq.nlargest(2, iterable))
[(500, 3), (400, 2)]
```

For larger `n` see @SilentGhost's post.

---

Edit: Benchmarked some solution:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import heapq
from timeit import Timer

seq = [100, 2, 400, 500, 400]

def a(seq):
    """returns [(3, 500), (2, 400)]"""
    return heapq.nlargest(2, enumerate(seq), key=lambda x: x[1])

def b(seq):
    """returns [3, 2]"""
    return map(seq.index, heapq.nlargest(2, seq))

def c(seq):
    """returns [(500, 3), (400, 2)]"""
    map(lambda n: (n, seq.index(n)), heapq.nlargest(2, seq))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    _a = Timer("a(seq)", "from __main__ import a, seq")
    _b = Timer("b(seq)", "from __main__ import b, seq")
    _c = Timer("c(seq)", "from __main__ import c, seq") 

    loops = 1000000

    print _a.timeit(number=loops)
    print _b.timeit(number=loops)
    print _c.timeit(number=loops)

    # Core i5, 2.4GHz, Python 2.6, Darwin
    # 8.92712688446
    # 5.64332985878
    # 6.50824809074
```

Comment: @SilentGhost, please explain. At least in a simple benchmark `iterable.index` seems nearly twice as fast (see my edit).

Comment: @Roque: what do your benchmark worth if you're comparing solution that works (mine) with solutions that don't (yours)? Despite linking to the `index` docs you haven't probably noticed very important bit there: "Return the index in the list of the **first** item [...]"

Comment: @Roque: well, sure, when `n = 2` you see what you see, how does your "solution" performs with `n = 10`?

Comment: `n = 10` yields the same performance results. for an array of length 10000 and `n = 100` you win, congrats ;)